# How can I make GNU screen not auto close when the command I give it finishes?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I run the following command

```
screen -S session echo hello
```

It runs and exits immediately,

```
[screen is terminating]
```

because echo finishes immediately. Is there a way to keep the screen running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
screen -S session sh -c 'echo hello ; read x'
```

There's also a `defzombie` command, which causes dead windows to remain open; `man screen` or `info screen` for more information.